# how can I get a column of window average without grouping it?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to add a new column, which is the average of an existing column, and I won't the new column to show the same average number in every row.

the table is like

[image: orignal table]

and what I want is like:

[image: a table with a new average column]

I know it's super easy to do in Excel, but I want to do it in SQL, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `OVER` window function for the average:

```
declare @t table (
  Id int primary key,
  Sales money not null
);

insert into @t (Id, Sales)
values
  (1,34),
  (2,23),
  (3,543),
  (4,234);

select t.Id, t.Sales, avg(t.Sales) over() as [Average]
from @t t;
```

If you need your averages to be grouped by any criteria, put them into the `OVER(partition by ...)`.

Comment: Hi Thank you. But I use SQL server, does it work under sql server too?

Comment: @miemiemime, of course, this should work on 2012 at least, most probably on 2005 (can't check this myself, have no 2005 server around). The `values` constructor was first introduced in 2008, but it's not a part of an actual query, it's just a sample data. You have `sql-server` tag in your question, of course the answers are MSSQL-specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AVG` in a window function over the entire table:

```
SELECT id, sales, AVG(sales) OVER() AS [avg]
FROM dbo.Sales;
```